# Date formate showing one day delay in swift5

Tags: swift, date, io, nsdateformatter

In my application for selecting of date, I use the date picker with "MM-dd-yyyy" format again send back to the backend with "yyyy-MM-dd" format with the following code.

```
func DateFromApptoWeb(_ date: String) -> String
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    }
```

Here I am displaying date with my format getting from backend format with the following method.

```
func DateFromWebtoApp(_ date: String) -> String
        {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "America/New_York")
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
            return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
        }
```

But when I display the date it is showing one day delay.

Comment: What is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`? Why are there three formats? I thought there are only 2 - your "app" format and the "web" format.

Comment: Can you also [edit] your question to give some sample inputs and outputs to show that it is delayed by one day? We'd like a [mcve].

Comment: Show your actual date string that you are trying to parse. Note that adding Z to the end of your date formatter dateFormat it will try to parse a timezone present in the end of your dateString. You should set your date formatter to "en_US_POSIX" when parsing a fixed dateFormat and if you want to display the corresponding NewYork time for the parsed date you should set the date formatter's timezone instead of its locale.